# Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать функцию Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста правильно написать функцию,
мне нужно получить этот результат только в одной функции:
[image: Правильный результат]

```
def log_request(req: 'flask_request' , res: 'str') -> None:
    '''Функция принимает два аргумента <req> и <res> с функции <do_search>'''
    #Аргумент <req> принимает текуший обьек запроса
    #Аргумент <res> принимает результат вызова <number>
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log: 
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num1'] , res ,file=log , sep='|')

def log_request2(req: 'flask_request' , res: 'str') -> None:
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num2'] , res ,file=log , sep='|')

def log_request3(req: 'flask_request' , res: 'str') -> None:
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num3'] ,  res, file=log , sep='|')
```

ожидаю от кода , нужно чтобы с первой операции do_search записался первый print , далее функция log_request пропустила нижние 2 принта до выполнения следушей операции do_search , когда выполниться вторая операция должен записаться только второй print а первый и третий должны пропуститься , когда сработает 3 операция do_search то должный 1 и 2 print пропуститься а третий записаться.

```
def log_request(req: 'flask_request' , res: 'str') -> None:
    '''Функция принимает два аргумента <req> и <res> с функции <do_search>'''
    #Аргумент <req> принимает текуший обьек запроса
    #Аргумент <res> принимает результат вызова <number>
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:     
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num1'] , res ,file=log , sep='|')
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num2'] , res ,file=log , sep='|')       
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num3'] ,  res, file=log , sep='|')
```

[image: неправильный результат]

извините за глупый вопрос, я только учусь, поинтересоваться не у кого((

Comment: Не особо понятно, о каком результате речь? Что ожидаете от кода?

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста , я исправил вопрос)

Comment: Честно говоря я все равно ничего не понял, но это дело во мне, так что пусть лучше кто-то другой попробует разобраться :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
n = 0

def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: 'str') -> None:
    '''Функция принимает два аргумента <req> и <res> с функции <do_search>'''
    #Аргумент <req> принимает текущий объект запроса
    #Аргумент <res> принимает результат вызова <number>

    global n
    n += 1

    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:     
        print(req.form['num_jek'], req.form['my_num'+str(n)] , res ,file=log , sep='|')
```

Но помните, что использовать `global` - не есть хорошо. Просто не зная остальной ваш код довольно сложно что-то советовать. :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное , то что нужно.
Можете пожалуйста пояснить почему использовать global - не есть хорошо?) мне бы он очень пригодился в других функциях.

Comment: @UserName Долго объяснять. Пока у вас небольшой код, в принципе можно так делать. Но когда кода много, использование глобальных переменных часто ведёт к путанице и к невозможности отследить как меняется состояние объекта во времени, кто и как его использует и меняет. Лучше использовать объектную модель и либо передавать нужные данные как параметр функции, либо, если нет такой возможности, хранить данные в каком-то своём самописном объекте, а функция вызываемая пусть будет методом этого объекта и берёт данные из своего объекта, а не из global. Как-то так.